# Risky compiler bugs - what compiler to use for critical applications

Tags: compiler-errors

When I started programming, I used to assume that compilers can be relied on to produce correct output (if code is correct, then binary should produce correct results). Later I learned that compilers do have bugs and glitches which may produce undefined or somewhat wrong behaviour for marginal cases. But recently, I stumbled upon a bug that scared me - intel's `c++` compiler started producing blatantly wrong results with simple arithmetic operations (in essence, `2+2!=4` with this compiler). After ruling out my mistake, I found that the bug was reported already: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/675477

In essence, automatic vectorization (which is used in most cases by default) produces nonsense assembly which applies addition in wrong dimensions of a multidimensional array (the bug report mentions parallelization but it happens in the simplest single threaded cases, too).

As this is the intel compiler, which is backed by a huge corporation and users pay for it, I assumed such a critical bug would be fixed immediately (if nothing else, by producing a warning or turning off vectorization by default), but it appears that the reaction to the issue was disproportionately underwhelming and the next version stil has the issue.

To me, this issue looks critical because it silently produces wrong results on basic arithmetics, and I can easily see this producing erroneous data in scientific research, analysis of medical data, or worse, safety-critical applications. It could also be exploitable.

My use case is thankfully none of that, but my question is: what compilers can be best trusted for critical applications? Which have the fastest response time when an issue occurs? How often do such bugs occur? Are there established ways (on top of extensive testing, of course) to ensure the compiled program corresponds to the original source code?

This is a soft question.

Comment: Standard cost/benefit trade-off. Roll your own compiler if it's worth the investment. Cheapo solution: use all of gcc, clang and intel in your tests to majority vote against buggy compiler output.

Comment: I think rolling your own compiler is even more error-prone - classic rookie mistake of writing things from scratch. In addition to everything, one would have to test the undoubtably buggy new compiler (and ditch all the knowledge and optimization done by others).

Comment: But the comparison methods seems reasonable :)